# Class Template C++ Errors

Tags: c++, templates

Updated the files and I still get the following errors.

- 1 Unresolved externals (lab12.exe line 1)
- unresolved external symbol "public char__thiscall Pair::geetFirst(void)" (?getFirst@?$Pair@D@@QAEDXZ) referenced in function_main (lab12.obj line 1)

**Pair.h**

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class Pair
{

private:
    T theFirst;
    T theSecond;

public:
    /*Pair(const T& dataOne, const T& dataTwo);*/
    Pair(T a, T b) {
        theFirst = a;
        theSecond = b;
    }
    T getFirst();
    T getSecond();

};
```

**Pair.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Pair.h"


template<class T>
T Pair<T>::getFirst()
{
    return theFirst;
}

template<class T>
T Pair<T>::getSecond()
{
    return theSecond;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Pair.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Pair <char> letters('a', 'd');

    cout << letters.getFirst();


    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have thought that the constructor of pair would initialize `theFirst=dataOne` and `theSecond=dataTwo`

Comment: You have dramatically changed the question. The previous answers were applicable, now that are not. It would have been a better idea to ask another question.

Comment: I did, and they marked it as a duplicate. So I just changed what I was told to fix the naming error and moved the implementation in the .h file.. other than that everything is the same. I updated the question with the new error since they would not let me ask a new one as it was too close i guess!

Comment: The error is solve by implementing everything in the header file, the duplicate contains some good answers. I think you should revert this question to the original error and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been bit by `using namespace std;`. You have your own `pair` class, but there's a `std::pair` in the standard library. The compiler can't decide which one to use, so you get an ambiguous symbol error.

Solution: [Don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077)! Qualify standard library symbols with `std::` instead. It saves a lot of headaches like this.

Comment: Got it, I believe I fixed it, but I am still getting an error I have never seen. Because it is in the .exe and .obj file I have no idea what the issue is... any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace std also contains a template class called pair.

You will want to wrap your own pair template in its own namespace or name it to something else so you can call it without an ambiguous symbol error.

Comment: Got it, I believe I fixed it, but I am still getting an error I have never seen. Because it is in the .exe and .obj file I have no idea what the issue is... any advice?